# Array search works just with making a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I made this function to search an array and it did not work, I figured it had something to do with passing the array.  So I was trying different things out. It started working when I just simply MADE a pointer to the array, I did not do anything with it, why is that?

```
void search(int a[],int n,int find);

int main(void){
    int size;
    int arr[]={345,767,232,45,768,2342,78,-89,-354,-234};

    int *p=arr;

    size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    search(arr[size+1],size,-89);
    return 0;
}
void search(int a[],int len,int find){
    int spot,i,FOUND;
    spot=i=FOUND=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        if (a[i]==find){
            FOUND=1;
            break;
        }
        if (FOUND==1){
            printf("%d found at element %d\n",find, i);
        }
        else
            printf("Number: %d \tNOT FOUND",find);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I had to put 'size+1' in passing the function in order for it to work, whats the reason for that?

Comment: please indent you code

Comment: I was told this before, i did in order for it to show up as code, how else should I indent? Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

The basic problem of this code is in

```
 search(arr[size+1],size,-89);
```

where you try to access `arr[size+1]` which is array out of bound access. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, `C` uses 0-based indexing for arrays, so for an array having size `n`, `arr[n]` is also effectively out of bound access. The valid access will be `arr[0]` to `arr[n-1]`.

You should only pass `arr`, the array name, which automatically decays to a pointer to the first element when passed as function argument.

On the other hand, when you do

```
int *p=arr;
```

and pass `p`, you're effectively storing the pointer to the first element of the array to `p`, and passing that to the function, (which is expected), so it works fine.

That said, just a suggestion,

```
 size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

can be re-written as

```
size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

to make is more robust.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).